# About datetime class python

Tags: python, class

why this statement

```
print(datetime.date(2023,12,4).strftime('%A'))
```

give me a wrong output : Monday
however the right output as you know is Wednesday.

I think the problem maybe in my machine but i used others and same output in online and local

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  According to https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html, ```datetime.date()'s```  parameters are (year, month, day), so your 2023 12 4 is actually december 4th, 2023, which is a Monday.  What you want is ```datetime.date(2023,4,12)```

Answer (score 2):

You're confused with the order of arguments. Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime):

> `class datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)`

and `datetime.date(2023,12,4)`, which is 2023 Dec 4th, is indeed a Monday.

2023 Apr 12th is a Wednesday though.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(datetime.date(2023,12,4).strftime('%A'))
```

is month=12 and day=4 so it return Monday

you should try this `print(datetime.date(2023,4,12).strftime('%A'))`

or `datetime.datetime.strptime("2023/4/12", "%Y/%d/%m").strftime('%A')`